# Why does ng-include use 2 sets of quotes?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

ng-include expects angular expression evaluating to URL, So when we write  ng-include="page.html" that mean html attribute of page object of $scope. And when we write ng-include=" 'page.html' " (single quote around page.html, which is surrounded by double quotes) that is angular expression: string that evaluates to value page.html

Answer (score 8):

All the names inside angular directives depicts the angular's default behavior. Just think that what you are putting inside the double quotes are simple variable names to angular. Like `ng-include="page.html"`, Angular takes it as you have mentioned to access the property named `html` of the object named `page` in the `scope` variable. And in your case when you want to pass a raw string instead of variable names then you put further quotes (single quotes) to let angular know that the parameter you are passing is a string and not any variable of the scope. Like `ng-include=" 'page.html'"`.

Hope that clears your confusion.